# Commutation relation of a operator with Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, commutator, hamiltonian, observables

Given that the eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian operator $H$ are bounded below, will a Hermitian operator $T$ exist such that $[T, H] = i\hbar{\bf 1}$ identity operator?

Comment: See [Pauli's theorem](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=pauli's+theorem+time). Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6584/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34243/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/96251/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I proceeded like this: let T be a hermitian operator satisfying the above condition.Let |phi0> be a a eigen ket of the H operator having the least eigen value E0.applying the commutator on both the eigen ket I am getting 1=0 or something like that.where I am going wrong?